# scala: for comprehension with Option

Tags: scala

I have an Option of a Seq of some items:

```
Option[Seq[MyItem]]
```

MyItem has a field 'description'

I need to find whether one of the items has a specific description.

How can it be done using for comprehension?

Comment: Can you explain why the solution needs to use `for`? I fear that this is an [XY question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to test whether any element of `Option[Seq[MyItem]]` has a specific description then you can do this.

```
opt.exists(_.exists(_.description == ???))
```

If you really need a solution that uses `for` then I can't help you :)

Comment: Actually I am doing this currently. But I fear readability is not that good, so I was looking for for comprehensions. But seems for comprehensions don't work when first generator has Option to deal with.

Comment: Readability depends on the audience, but for a competent Scala programmer the `exists` version is very clear. `for` is appropriate for processing one collection into another, but this task is to produce a single value from a collection. For that you need a `fold` or `collect` operation but that is not going to be any clearer than `exists`.

Comment: A single for-comprehension on `Option[Seq[MyItem]]` will not work.
However it will work on `Seq[Option[MyItem]]`.   
Just use exists\fold\collect as mentioned by @Tim